# How to hold temporary object list in each .net core API request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In my .net core api more than 200 modules are executing of a single request, and having 500 database call, maximum sql queries are calling several times in a loop with same parameter. My application is deployed in AWS EKS.

How to hold temporary object list in a .net core api request? So that we can reduce the database call? It can also reduce the response time.

I can do this using static class but it can impact the load a AWS EKS container.

**So without session is there any mechanism and best practices that can help to hold the data to entire session and re use that data without calling same sql query?**

Comment: Yes, there is. It is called "caching". However, I fear you have to provide more details and get more specific for better advice.

Comment: Caching also can impact memory issue in AWS Cluster.

Comment: Maybe, but you have to pay some price, haven't you? Either repeat expensive SQL queries, or keep their result somewhere. That somewhere will take memory.

Comment: In order to deal with your scenario you could use [`ASP.NET Core IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-imemorycache). You could have look here for [`implementation details`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cache-guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few strategies, you're talking about caching responses.

You can implement IMemoryCache and have it within your application. The "downside" is that if you have multiple instances running at the same time they will all have different caches because memory is, well, memory. So if you have one instance and the data is not really that big, is fine.

Another approach is to use something like Redis and store keys with respective responses and implement TryGet from there before calling your actual database or source of data.

Another approach is to use hosting cache, something like Cloudflare to cache specific endpoints with specific parameters if possible. (ecommerce usually uses that, for example... caching a list of products by filters or caching a product page)

Personally, on my private projects, I use a mix of memory with redis. Using memory for application configuration and things that are important for the app itself and client data almost always goes to redis, having a few endpoints running under no cache policies.